# First value in global list is being updated within function somehow?

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment

For Some reason the first value in the list x is being updated but nothing else in the list is being updated. I am confused as x is a global variable and is only updated within the replace function. The program works if I redeclare x between print statements. I have commented it out as it feels like a sloppy solution.

```
x = [1,3,2,4,2,1,1,2,2,1] 

def REPLACE(new,old,x):
    if str(old) not in str(x):
        return x
    elif x[0] == old:
        x[0] = new
        return x[0:1] + REPLACE(new,old,x[1:])
    else:
        return x[0:1] + REPLACE(new,old,x[1:])


print(REPLACE(10,1,x))
#x = [1,3,2,4,2,1,1,2,2,1]
print(REPLACE(1,3,REPLACE(1,3,x)))
```

Comment: `if str(old) not in str(x):` No, that's not how is should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change its value in REPLACE function. since you are forming new list, you don't have to do it. Just read x, not changing it.

```
x = [1,3,2,4,2,1,1,2,2,1] 

def REPLACE(new,old,x):
    if str(old) not in str(x):
        return x
    elif x[0] == old:
        return [new] + REPLACE(new,old,x[1:])
    else:
        return x[0:1] + REPLACE(new,old,x[1:])


print(REPLACE(10,1,x))
print(REPLACE(1,3,REPLACE(1,3,x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `REPLACE` function, the only statement that alters `x` is:

```
x[0] = new
```

which modifies only the first item of `x`, while:

```
return x[0:1] + REPLACE(new,old,x[1:])
```

creates slices of `x`, which are new list instances, so further changes to the slices would not be reflected in the original `x`.

If you intend to make this function both alter `x` and return the result while remaining recursive, you can use an index as a parameter instead:

```
def REPLACE(new, old, x, i=0):
    if i >= len(x):
        return x
    if x[i] == old:
        x[i] = new
    return REPLACE(new, old, x, i + 1)
```